# In Storm, BaseRichSpout class takes time to call ack and fail method

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am new in storm. I have a spout class that extends BaseRichSpout and Bolt BaseRichBolt.
Spout class:

```
public class Spout extends BaseRichSpout{
SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
Stirng ackId = null;
String message = null;
public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
    _collector = collector;
}
public void nextTuple() {
    System.out.println("  Entered Spout  \n");
    message = queue.take(); //I take message from Blocking queue;
    ackId = message;
    this._collector.emit(new Values(message), ackId);
}
public void ack(Object msgId) {
    System.out.println("Geting Acknowledges for :: " + msgId);
}
public void fail(Object msgId) {
    System.out.println("Geting Fail Acknowledges for :: " + msgId);
}
}
```

First Bolt:

```
public class Bolt1 extends BaseRichBolt {
private OutputCollector collector;
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context,OutputCollector collector) {
    this.collector = collector;
}
public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    String message = (String) tuple.getValueByField("msg");
    collector.emit(tuple, new Values(message));
    collector.ack(tuple);
}
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("msg"));

}

}
```

Second Bolt:

```
public class Bolt2 extends BaseRichBolt {
private OutputCollector collector;
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context,OutputCollector collector) {
    this.collector = collector;
}
public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    String message = (String) tuple.getValueByField("msg");
    System.out.println(message+ "jhon");
    collector.ack(tuple);
}
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {    

}

}
```

Topology Configuration:

```
TopologyBuilder tBuilder = new TopologyBuilder();
    tBuilder.setSpout("spout", new Spout(),1);
    tBuilder.setBolt("bolt1", new Bolt1(),1).shuffleGrouping("spout");
    tBuilder.setBolt("bolt2", new Bolt2(),1).shuffleGrouping("bolt1");
```

I write one class to send data to Blocking queue. I start storm in local mode, when i send data into Blocking Queue, i get acknowledge for few of message not for all messages. If i send again bunch of data then i get previous acknowledge for message and some acknowledge for current message not all current message.

**In this way I Faced this Problem:**

when i send bunch of data to Blocking Queue and all are process through storm but i not get acknowledge for all message and then storm is down. So, that time i don't know the message is process successfully or fail.

*I have some temporary solution:*
 when i sleep spout for few second before taking message from Blocking Queue that time i get acknowledge for all message.But in this case when second Bolt get some time to process the message then again i not get the acknowledge for message.

Please can anyone give solution for that problem.

Comment: Is it possible that blocking queue is returning the same object, over and over, with different values?  Middleware sometimes does that.  If that's the case, then you're effectively sending the same messageID for every tuple out of the spout.

Comment: I put different values by using for loop. But i get acknowledge of all message when i put sleep in nextTuple method in spout class.